# How do you prove indeterminate form using epsilon and delta?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta, indeterminate-forms

The question, for instance, is proving $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x+1}=1$$

This is my answer, which is likely incorrect.

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists M \in \mathbb{R}$$  such that $$ x>M \Rightarrow \left|\frac{x}{x+1}-1\right|<\epsilon$$

$$\left|\frac{x}{x+1}-1\right|<\epsilon \iff
\frac{1}{|x+1|}<\epsilon \iff |x+1|>\frac1\epsilon$$

I then get $x>\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}$

Picking $M=\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}$,  I get $$x>M=\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}\Rightarrow x>\frac1\epsilon - 1 \Rightarrow \cdots \Rightarrow \left|\frac{x}{x+1}-1\right|<\epsilon$$

Could anybody please point out which part should I add or fix?

Comment: It's fine, albeit slightly redundant. Some people would prefer to treat the calculation where you got to $|x+1|>1/\epsilon$ as "scratch work", and in the "linear" part of the proof, you would just write "let $M=\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$, then for $x>M$, ..."

Comment: The math looks good so let me give you a latex/mathjax tip instead. You can use `\left| ... \right|` to get the right size of the absolute value signs. Works with `(`  and `[` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning in general looks to me fine. But let me provide a "neater" argument for your reference:

If $x \neq -1$, then
$$
\bigg| \frac{x}{x+1} - 1 \bigg| = \frac{1}{|x+1|};
$$
given any $\varepsilon > 0$,
we have $\frac{1}{|x+1|} < \varepsilon$ if $x > \frac{1}{\varepsilon} - 1$.